# Regular price in invoice pdf

Tags: magento

I want to show regular price as well as special price in invoice PDF. For this I have used an extension(EaDesign) but the variable responsible for price is printing special price not regular price. Can anybody guide me please ? Thanks

Comment: Could you please post your (relevant) code?

Comment: Thanks for reply.I got the solution. For this I had to load product by sku in items.php and get regular price separately.I know this is the correct way but my problem resolved.